# How to run $and operator in mgo query in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, database

I want to execute following query in MongoDB in Golang

```
check_select = bson.M{
            "$and": []interface{}{
                "shr_key": user_shr_key,
                "id": uid,
                "user_history": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"action": "STOP", "message_id": mid}},
            },
        }
```

Please help... I am getting following error `"index must be non-negative integer constant"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is from the way you initialize an `array` in `go`:

```
....
"$and": []interface{}{
    "shr_key": user_shr_key,
....
```

`go` array doesn't accept `string` as an index.

Anyway, in order to solve your problem, remove index from array initialization and wrap the key-value pair in `bson.M` will do, eg:

```
bson.M{
            "$and": []bson.M{ // you can try this in []interface
                bson.M{"shr_key": user_shr_key},
                bson.M{"id": uid},
                bson.M{"user_history": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"action": "STOP", "message_id": mid}}},
            },
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But still I am getting following error                                                   "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue and needs an array"

Comment: Sorry my bad, @SyedQasimRizvi I have updated my answer, `$and` should accept an array which you are right. The trick is that you can remove the index during initialization and that is.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ch33hau. Still I am getting "not found" error. However there are records in mongodb satisfying this condition.

Comment: I would suggest you to remove the `user_history` and give a try on relatively simpler conditions first. Or maybe, try to hard-code some values before you fully confirmed the code is working.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ch33hau. Query is working fine if I removed "user-history" part. Moreover query is also working fine if I used only "user-history" part but it gives "not found" if I used all three conditions.

Comment: This is the problem in how you form the `mongodb` query, but you can give a try to not using `$elemMatch`, simply use `bson.M{"user_history.action", "STOP"}` and `bson.M{"user_history.message_id", mid}`, I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: One more thing @SyedQasimRizvi, Ultimately, when I was unfamiliar with `mongodb`, before creating any queries in `mgo` or other libraries, I will testing it on `mongodb cli` in order to reduce uncertainty.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ch33hau

Answer (score 1):

Here You Can See , Get Values by $Match , $and Using Golang MongoDB

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{bson.M{"storyID": storyID}, 
bson.M{"parentID": parentID}}}}
}
```